# how to allocate memory foe generic class without having a T()

Tags: c++, list, class, generics, constructor

I have a class and I want to write a generic sorted list that we can use it with that class:

```
class A
{
 int n;
 public:
  A(int n):n(n){}
};
```

and this how I thought to do my sorted list class

```
template <class T>
class SortedList
 {
  T* data;
  int size;
  int max_size;
  void expand();
  static const int EXPAND_RATE=2;
  static const int INITIAL_SIZE=10;
public:
SortedList();
};
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList():data(new T[INITIAL_SIZE]),size(0),max_size(INITIAL_SIZE){}
//                                  ^^^ here we need a T()
```

now the problem is that class A doesn't have a c'tor like this `A()`
does anyone have any Idea how can I write the sortedlist class without needing the `A()`??

PS: some people have recommended to do Nodes with `T data` and `next` but I can't see how can I do this, and how could this help? since we still need a `T()`

Edit: I tried now to do it this way:

```
template <class T>
class SortedList
 {
  T** data;
// ^^
  int size;
  int max_size;
  void expand();
  static const int EXPAND_RATE=2;
  static const int INITIAL_SIZE=10;
public:
SortedList();
};
template <class T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList():data(new T*[INITIAL_SIZE]),size(0),max_size(INITIAL_SIZE){}
```

now I am facing a different problem with this function:

```
void SortedList<T>::insert(const T& object)
{
 if(size>=max_size)
 {
     expand();
 }
 int index=0;
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
  T item=*data[i];
// when I try to print item nothing goes out
  if(item<object)
//      ^^^ here I get a segmentation fault
  {
    continue;
  }
  index=i;
  break;
 }
 size++;
 for (int i = size-1; i >index; i--)
 {
  data[i]=data[i-1]; 
 }
 T Item(object);
 T* ptr= &Item;
 data[index]=ptr;
 //when I print *data[index] it does get printed perfectly
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: Do you want a list or an array/vector?

Comment: @Jarod42 it's not allowed

Comment: @Jarod42 I basically want to write a generic list without the ability to use any STL

Comment: So use indeed Node (you won't have to handle capacity which is the problematic stuff).

Comment: Has your instructor gone over [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new)?

Comment: It sounds like your instructor is asking you to copy `std::list` (or possibly `std::forward_list`), not approximate `std::vector`

Comment: @Caleth yes this what they want.... after I read what is in the link of the `placement new` that you wrote now I am thinking can a `smart pointer` solve the problem?

Comment: @raghad placement new is unrelated to smart pointers. To approximate `std::vector` you'd `malloc` some raw memory, and when you wanted to insert `T elem` you could `new (data + size) T(std::move(elem))`, which would use a move constructor if available, and otherwise a copy constructor

Comment: But that's a really advanced thing to be doing. `std::vector` sounds like it is easy to re-implement, but when you look at *all* the things it promises, it's actually quite hairy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does anyone have any Idea how can I write the sortedlist class without needing the A()??

- Option 1: Allocate memory for each element separately. In other words, use a node based data stucture such as a linked list.
- Option 2: Separate allocation of memory from creation of the object. This can be achieved by using `std::allocator` to allocate the memory, and `std::construct_at` to create the object (use placement-new instead prior to C++20). This is how dynamic array-like data structures such as `std::vector` are implemented.

P.S. Manual memory management is challenging. If you attempt to do it without studying the subject in depth, you'll very likely write a broken program.

Comment: if I use a node should it be` struct node<T>` or class? and should the data field be `T data` or `T* data`?

Comment: @raghad Structs are classes. You can use either. The only difference between using `struct` classkey and the `class` classkey is the default access specifier. If you define the node class outside the list, then yes it would have to be a template. But if you define it as a nested class inside the list template, then that's not  necessary. It would be wasteful to allocate the data separately, so I recommend `T`.